# Can I save Faridah Malik?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I just got back to China the second time around.  After our helicopter was shot down, Malik tells me to run while the guards are distracted by the chopper.  On my way out, I tried killing as many guards as possible, but she was still killed along with the helicopter.  If I was able to take down all the guards (and the robot) fast enough, could I have saved her?

Comment: I don't know how to reword the title to make it less spoilerish.

Comment: @yx_ Yeah, I couldn't think of a better way of wording it either.  If anyone else has an idea, please feel free to edit

Comment: Let's not over convolute/obfuscate the original question just to remove a small spoiler.  Especially since the game has been out for 5 years already.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes you can.  I managed to do it on Deus Ex mode.  Here are a few things that may help out:

1. Use those exploding barrels.  You can use those to take out enemies that are nearby.
2. If you have a long ranged weapon like sniper rifle, it helps out a lot.  You have to take out those heavies fast as they do tons of damage.
3. Get the attention of the big bot that gets dropped.  If you can toss two emp grenades over, he'll die.  If you don't have any, shoot it a few times so he's focused on you instead.

You can still save her on a pacifist playthrough, but its much harder.

Here's a [video walkthrough](http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/715666/deus-ex-human-revolution-how-to-save-malik-walkthrough/) on how to do it.

The reward for saving Malik is:

> She later assists you by saving the Sarif scientists in Singapore and dealing with a bunch of enemies with an emp blast so you don't have to face them.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try harder on my next playthrough, I suppose.

Comment: What are the rewards if your successful?

Comment: @Rob_IGS added the reward

Comment: I had no grenades, but I was able to take out the bot with a heavy rifle by peaking around the right of the right-most cover thingy and just holding down the mouse button.  For some reason, it couldn't hit me - I didn't lose any life at all.

Comment: Seems like the (upgraded) Typhoon might be the best way to knock out all those enemies quickly enough to save her. Anyone tried that?

Comment: And if you don't have a sniper rifle, immediately break left with a good close-range weapon (like a shotgun with the 2x shot upgrade).  Ignore the snipers to begin with, and focus on the support troops.  Pick off the heavies from behind as they start to advance on the chopper.  When the robot drops, finish off the snipers and engage it from above.

Answer (score 25):

Here's a little walkthrough if you're on Pacifist (so no exploding barrels etc.)

1. Shoot the two heavies with Tranq darts from where you stand.
2. Sprint around to the right (don't bother cloaking or being subtle, the enemies won't focus on you until you're too close or shooting at them)
3. Pull out your stun gun and starting with the one guy on the bottom floor and working your way up the stairs to the next floors, takedown (non-lethal) and stungun every guy you see. They'll be too focused on Malik to put up much resistance.
4. After you've cleared out the first floor (not the ground floor) there should only be about 3 guys left, one sniper above you, and two guys (one more sniper) in the other building.
5. Whether you want to take the sniper out or take out the other guy first and then take out both snipers is up to you, but with the snipers slow rate of fire they're not much of a threat.

It took me about 10 reloads before I tried this and it worked the first time. Keep in mind however that I'd learned the layout in those 10 tries so it might not work for you the first time.

Comment: This strategy worked for me, with the caveat that, on Deus Ex mode, the heavies took 3 tranqs to the head each to take down, which took waaaay too much time.  Instead, I ran immediately to the right, took out the first guy, ate an energy bar, cloaked, and took out both heavies with a stun-gun *(which only took one hit each - without cloaking, they shot at me and I died immediately)*.  On the second try on Deus Ex mode, I managed to do it, without killing one, and taking no damage :D

Comment: What about the bot, though?

Answer (score 6):

I saved her on Deus Ex difficulty while maintaining the pacifist achievement.  It was actually pretty easy if you had the right equipment.

1. You are going to need max level cloak, tranquilizer rifle, EMP grenade and a lot of CyberBoost bars
2. Immediately cloak and run directly at the heavies and knock them out.  After this, focus on the combat rifle guys on the ground.
3. When the robot comes out, EMP it.  If anyone dies from the resulting self destruct, it does NOT break pacifist behavior.
4. When the guys on the ground and the robot are KO'd, you can let cloak expire.
5. Quickly use your tranquizer rifle to stun the snipers on the upper level.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the right augmentations and enough bars, it's easy. Just take a right, everyone will be focused on the chopper so you can use take-out on all the enemies on the right, without even being shot at. When you reach the bot, go invisible, use typhoon as far away from the human mobs as possible and you can take down the bot without anyone dying.

Then, climb up the stairs, take down the second floor on the right wing, then on the top floor make sure to hit that sniper from the side or the front. Otherwise you will punch him off and he dies. Then jump down, take down the remaining mobs on the ground, then use the container to jump onto the last sniper and take him down as well.

For this, you'll need:

- 3-6 bars
- fully upgraded Typhoon augmentation
- jump augmentation
- invisible augmentation (not really required, but nice when you get shot a)

Comment: I dont think you even need a cloak. I ran around and tasered everyone. I have the 9ft jump enhancement so all i did was jump and taser. and typhoon-ed the bot

Answer (score 3):

On Normal difficulty, with the PC version, I was able to save her by rather messily taking down the heavies, EMPing the robots, and then pistol sniping everyone else. Managed to do it fast enough.. I was just lucky I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

I managed it pretty easily using the revolver. I was only on Normal mode, and not aiming for pacifist, but never the less, revolver with laser sight and exploding rounds clears them out in no time. Also had an EMP mine which I chucked at the robot =)

Answer (score 2):

Rooster Teeth did a guide on this because saving her is an achievement

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is obviously harder.
My weapons used:
tranquilizers: 12 darts
Stun gun: 2 clips
PEPS: not used
EMP grenades: 2
Add ons needed:cloaking (at least basic), and the aim tracking on tranquilizer gun really helps.

Basically, take out the three guys (by my count) with heavy rifles with the tranq darts.
As the guys move closer, use your cloak and stun gun to take out the ground troops. Stand back, cloak and take out the sniper (tranquilizers). At some point the robot will appear. Toss two emps two solve that problem. Then shoot the two guys on the roof with tranquilizers and you're done. Took me 5 tries. mostly to get the layout and order right.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in a 'Pacifist' way. Maxed out health. Four energy cells. Invisibility, running, takedowns on the base floor, EMP mine for the mech, takedowns on the first roof & tranq rifle for the snipers. One HypoStim & two CyberBoost ProEnergy Jar. Very cool. It is just like a Ninja.
I believe that with the Typhoon, among with the upgraded revolver, it should be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I went in with no ammo period -- I wasn't prepared for this mission at all so I ended up getting up close and personal.

If you pick up a green barrel and charge the heavies you're essentially carrying a shield; you can then take them down melee style and pick up their weapons. Then you can shoot at the bot to make it attack you, and then it's a matter of going up the building and taking out all the other guys until you get to the sniper.

After taking him out you can use his rifle to take out the remaining soldiers left; there is some heavy rifle ammo by the building on the right that you can pick up and finish off the robot with it. If you do not have heavy rifle you can get one from the heavies you took down earlier. Also there are a lot of combat rifles dropped if that's more your style.

Answer (score 1):

I went pacifist and it was far easier than trying to shoot everyone.  Work from the right hand side and take down the heavy rifles quickly, them EMP grenade for the bot.  Then just mop up the rest - job done!

Answer (score 0):

I came into this fight completely unprepared. It took me about seven or eight tries, but I saved her.

I ran up the right side and cloaked, then repeatedly ran back and forth across the elevator, looking straight at the ground, laying a couple of mines in front of the elevator each time - first frag mines, then EMPs on the second pass to kill the bot.

I got lucky on one of these runs and there were few enough enemies left after the frag mines and robot explosion that I was able to kill them all by gunfire before Malik died.

As goofy as it was to use proximity mines to win this fight, they were all I really had - no sniper rifle, no tranquilizer gun, and I wasn't fast enough for headshots to make headway.

If I had had the Typhoon at level 2 at that point, I probably just would have used it three or four times with very similar effects.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is one Sniper-rifle. From where the level begins give each Heavytrooper one headshot and they both focus on you... after the 2nd headshot (if you didnt pimp your sniper) they are fish food. This triggers the Robot to be dropped, but before they drop it shoot the Barrel too the left, first floor. Then shoot the sniper to the right (2nd floor), meanwhile the Robot should be there. Kill it with your RPG, EMP's, or regular weaponry. The remaining Troopers are no problem for the Malik, and Jenson ^^

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy to do when not on pacifist.

Start out by jumping down and taking cover. The helicopter will be right in front of you. To the right, there's a load of them, so take out as many as you can from here. 
Stay behind this cover until the guys with the heavy rifles come. Kill them both (shots to the head using armor-piercing guns).

Around about now the robot will drop in. The best way to kill it is using the typhoon (make sure you have the killing robots augmentation). Take cover as soon as you do since the robot self-destructs.

Take out the last of the men, including the two snipers on the third floors.

As soon as they are all dead, Malik flys away :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the guys that do the most damage first. With the sniper rifle I took out the heavy rifle guys first since they cause the most damage before the giant mech gets dropped. It takes two shots to the head. Then I sniped the snipers and as many of the other guys as I could until the mech is dropped. You have to take it out right away because it causes damage to the helicopter quickly. One EMP grenade does the trick. shooting red barrels takes out a bunch of soldiers. The exploding mech takes out some too. It took me tens of tries to get this. [here's a play.tv clip](http://plays.tv/s/Kn9Ds-Y3bygR)